# Elasticsearch / Tire : Facets Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

How can you specify the order of facets in Tire?

Its possible in Elasticsearch as seen here:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet.html

In tire its defaults to 'count' however I cant figure out how to change it to the 'term' order.

Here is my search method:

```
def self.search(params)
tire.search do
  query do
    boolean do
      must { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
    end
  end
  facet "article_ratings" do
    terms :article_rating
  end
  # raise to_curl
end
```

end

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out...

```
facet "article_ratings" do
    terms :article_rating, :order => 'term'
  end
```